# Тест функции в JUnit

Tags: java, junit

А именно как протестировать: String tasteToString()  ?

```
package sample;

/**
 * Класс Еда
 */
class Food extends Item {

    /** Вкус блюда*/
    private Taste taste;

    /**
     * Конструктор с параметрами
     * @param ItemName название блюда
     */
    Food(String ItemName) {
        super(ItemName);
        this.taste = Taste.TASTELESS;
    }

    /**
     * Конструктор с параметрами
     * @param taste вкус блюда
     * @param ItemName название блюда
     */
    Food(Taste taste, String ItemName){
        super(ItemName);
        this.taste = taste;
    }

    /**
     * @return вкус блюда
     */
    Taste getTaste() {
        return taste;
    }

    /**
     * @return строку, эквивалентную вкусу блюда
     */
    String tasteToString() {
        switch (taste)
        {
            case SWEET: return "Сладкий";
            case SOUR: return "Кислый";
            case SALTY: return "Солёный";
            case BITTER: return "Горький";
        }
        return "Безвкусный";
    }
}
```

Comment: Рекомендую отказаться от Taste и сделать столько классов, сколько элементов Taste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Test
public void tasteToString() {
    Food water = new Food("Water");
    assertEquals("Безвкусный", water.tasteToString());
}
```

Я бы сделал параметризованный enum.

Comment: да,да, есть такой :enum Taste {
    SWEET, //Сладкий
    SALTY, //Солёный
    SOUR, //Кислый
    BITTER, //Горький
    TASTELESS; //Безвкусный
}

Comment: @Daniil вот его бы я и сделал с параметрами.